# how to select multiple max values from column in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following two tables TBLSession and TBLStudentFeeRecord having following sample datasets

```
TBLSession:

   SessionId    SessionName  SessionStartMonth       SessionEndMonth
      1           2018-2019    2018-03-24               2019-02-24
      2           2019-2020    2019-01-30               2019-12-30
      3           2020-2021    2020-01-30               2021-12-30

TBLStudentFeeRecord:
  StudentId     SessionId   TutionFee   BranchId    ClassId   SectionId
    1001                1     1000       1              1         1
    1001                2     2000       1              3         1
    1001                3     1000       2              2         1
```

Now,what i am trying to achieve is to select two maximum sessions TutionFee of selected StudentId. I can use max(columnName) to get one maximum value from that particular column. Now how can i get two maximum sessions? 
Following dataset is required after querying these table

```
ResultDataSet:
  StudentId     SessionId   TutionFee   SessionName      

    1001                2     2000       2019-2020            
    1001                3     1000       2020-2021
```

What will be the query to achieve above dataset?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: How did you decide session 3 over session 1 since they both have a tuition fee of 1000?

Comment: Also if this really is your database, go back and spell **tuition** correctly.

Comment: why dont you "group by SessionId"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL Row_Number function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) with Partition By clause if you want to get the 2 session info per student

Otherwise, use Row_number() function without Partition By clause

You can find explanations for two alternatives in the following SQL CTE statements

```
;with cte as (
select *, 
-- top 2 session per student
--  rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by studentid order by sessionid desc)
-- top 2 sessions
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by sessionid desc)
from TBLStudentFeeRecord
)
select
*
from cte
inner join TBLSession on TBLSession.sessionid = cte.sessionid
where rn <= 2
```

The output is as follows

[image]

You can modify the select list according to your requirements

Comment: best answer !! Neat and clean !!! Thanku so much  you saved my day.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted your tries, so try something like this:

Pseudo query:

```
select top 2 from (select TutionFee from TBLStudentFeeRecord 
    where StudentId = 1001
    order by TutionFee desc )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro but I have mentioned in my question that i need to query on maximum sessions not on tution fee

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil There is no session.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subselect Top 2 on the max TutionFee and SessionId

```
select a.* , t.TutionFee
from TBLSession a
inner JOIN (
select TOP 2 studentID, TutionFee, SessionId 
from TBLStudentFeeRecord 
where StudentId = 1001
order TutionFee desc, SessionID desc
) t on t.SessionId = a.SessionId
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT StudentId ,SessionId,TutionFee,SessionName 
FROM(
    SELECT TSF.StudentId ,TSF.SessionId,TSF.TutionFee,TS.SessionName
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TSF.TutionFee ORDER BY SessionId DESC)RN
    FROM TBLStudentFeeRecord TSF
    INNER JOIN TBLSession TS ON TS.SessionId=TSF.SessionId
    )D
WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
select TBLStudentFeeRecord.StudentId,  TBLStudentFeeRecord.SessionId, TBLStudentFeeRecord.TutionFee, TBLStudentFeeRecord.SessionName
from TBLStudentFeeRecord
inner join TBLSession on TBLSession.SessionId = TBLStudentFeeRecord.SessionId
where TBLStudentFeeRecord.StudentId =  1000
ORDER BY TBLStudentFeeRecord.TutionFee DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In general query languages are powerful if you face any difficult or any complex scenario just use stored procedure

## Two max..........................................

```
CREATE PROCEDURE twoMaxFrom()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE max1 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE max2 DOUBLE;

    DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT
                                    TutionFee
                                  FROM TBLStudentFeeRecord;
    -- 2. Declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    -- 3. Open the cursor
    OPEN emp_cursor;
    L: LOOP
      -- 4. Fetch next element
      FETCH emp_cursor
      INTO TutionFee;
      -- Handler will set finished = 1 if cursor is empty
      IF finished = 1
      THEN
        LEAVE L;
      END IF;
      SET max1 = 0;
      SET max2 = 0;
      IF max1 > max2 
      THEN
        SET max1 = TutionFee;
        SET max2 = max1;

      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    -- 5. Close cursor when done
    CLOSE emp_cursor;
    SELECT max1;
    SELECT max2;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using `join` and `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 2 StudentId
    ,t1.SessionId
    ,TutionFee
    ,SessionName
FROM TBLSession AS t1
INNER JOIN TBLStudentFeeRecord AS t2 ON t1.SessionId = t2.SessionId
WHERE t2.StudentId = 1001
ORDER BY t1.SessionId DESC
```